# ubuntu 12.04 is not detected by windows 7

Tags: 12.04, windows

Once i installed ubuntu along with windows 7 it was working fine. Later i was suppose to reinstall my windows 7, from then i'm not been able to login to ubuntu. I'm not getting the option to choose Ubuntu. Though i installed both in different drives. Please assist. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Windows, it installs it's own bootloader over grub, which does not probe for other operating systems, therefor hindering you unable to boot into Ubuntu. To solve the problem, reference the Ubuntu Wiki article for this particular problem: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score -1):

you can install EasyBCD software in Windows and it allows you to add the entry for Ubuntu into bootloader. Just add new entry with Grub 2 and it configures automatically.

It is pretty straighforward so you shouldn't have problems.

Michal